# Regular expression first name and last name

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to extract firstname and lastname from a string. User can write inside my input the following: FirstName, FirstName LastName (sometimes full name, sometimes only firstname).

This is my regular expression, but it doesn't cover all the situations:

```
preg_match('/^(?<lastName>[^\s]+)[\s](?<firstName>.+)$/', $input, $matches);
```

This code will work for input like: A B, A B C D E, but not for A.

10x.

Comment: Can you share an example of the string that you're trying to extract from?

Comment: If user write "LastName FirstName" the result should be $matches['lastName'] = "LastName" and $matches['firstName'] = "FirstName". If the input is: Test, than the result should be $matches['lastName']="Test".

Comment: In the most of cases user will write something like this Snow John, but there are some possibilities when he will write only Snow.

Comment: @AmitThakur i don't undestrand your question. Just picture an input for name.

Comment: Alternatively,  what about simply splitting on spaces?

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles it is a solution, but i really what to use regular expression.

Comment: Any idea what it is wrong with my regexp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making the space and firstname portion optional (notice the `[\s]` and `(?<firstName>.+)` are wrapped in parenthesis followed by a question mark):

```
^(?<lastName>[^\s]+)([\s](?<firstName>.+))?$
```

...against "A" captures this:

```
MATCH 1
lastName    [0-1]   `A`
```

...and against "A B, A B C D E" this:

```
MATCH 1
lastName    [0-1]   `A`
2.  [1-14]  ` B, A B C D E`
firstName   [2-14]  `B, A B C D E`
```

Try it on for size: https://regex101.com/r/zO5zR6/1